# Run HTTP post on successful post login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, callback

I have a simple login, once user is logged in I have added a call back to run another post so that I have access to the post json to use in my system.

I think the way I have done it is correct however I am getting error

> GetData is not defined

Is this the correct way to do this

**JavaScript**

```
   $scope.LogIn = function () {
            $http({
                url: "http://www.somesite.co.uk/ccuploader/users/login",
                method: "POST",
                data: $.param({'username': $scope.UserName, 'password': $scope.PassWord}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function (response) {
                // success
                console.log('success');
                console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
                GetData();
                // location.href = '/cms/index.html';
            }, function (response) { // optional
                // failed
                console.log('failed');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        };


        $scope.UserData = function ($scope) {
            $scope.UserName = "";
            $scope.PassWord = "";
        };

        $scope.GetData = function () {
            $http({
                url: " http://www.somesite.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function (response) {
                // success
                console.log('you have received the data ');
                console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
                location.href = '/cms/index.html';
            }, function (response) { // optional
                // failed
                console.log('failed');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        };
```

Comment: $scope.GetData() != GetData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code to be `$scope.GetData();`.

Currently you are using `GetData()` which doesn't reference the same method. In fact it is `undefined` as per the error message.